# How to write a query in MongoDB to get data for last 7 days on rolling basis

Tags: mongodb, date

I am trying to build a MongoDB query to get last 7 days data on rolling basis. Can you help me how to write query to fetch data on dynamic dates.

Comment: How does your document look like?

Answer (score 2):

```
db.getCollection('collectioName').find({"dateField":{  $lt: new Date(), 
    $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-7))}})
```

Swap out the collectioName and dateField with what you have and it should work for ya!

Comment: This works also in 2023

Comment: @Ezeeroc better to specify what version you are working with that it works for rather than the year

Comment: This also works 3 years later for `"mongodb": "^3.1.10"` and `"mongoose": "^5.3.16"`

Answer (score 0):

To get last 7 days datas :

```
let lastWeek = new Date();
lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate() -7);
db.yourtable.find({ "yourelement": { $gte: lastWeek}} );
```

Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry i forgot 2 lines @WernfriedDomscheit

Answer (score 0):

For any `Date` operation in MongoDB I recommend the [moments.js](https://momentjs.com/) library:

```
db.collectioName.find({ "dateField": { $gte: moment().subtract(7, 'days').toDate() } })
```

If you like to get data older than "last midnight minus 7 days" then you would use

```
db.collectioName.find(
   { "dateField": { $gte: moment().startOf('day').subtract(7, 'days').toDate() } }
)
```